# Laravel Auditing - how i can add extra attribute to audits value (old_values and new_values) fields

Tags: laravel

I would like to add extra attributes to Laravel Auditing new_values and old_values attributes. (Laravel 6x, Laravel Auditing 12x)

Example new_values json field:

```
{"car_id":6,"odometer":"25200"}
```

What I would like:

```
{"car_id":6,"odometer":"25200","extra_field":"value"}
```

I have searched but couldn't find a solution yet. :(

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Maybe I should read the documentation more carefully...

https://laravel-auditing.com/docs/12.0/audit-transformation